# Integral with two variables

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is t treated as a constant in this equation?

$$J =\int (xt )dx$$

I understand how to reach a solution; I just do not understand the theory behind it.

Comment: *I just do not understand the theory behind it* **so you cannot** *understand how to solve it*

Comment: I understand how to reach the solution; I do not understand why the solution is reached this way.

Comment: "I understand how to reach the solution; I do not understand why the solution is reached this way." this is nonsense. Either you understand the solution or you don't.

Comment: I did not say I understood the solution; I said I understand how to reach the solution. For example, people might not understand how derivatives work, but they still know how to take a derivative.

Comment: @avid19: That's a bit absolutist. Of course it's possible to be able to execute an algorithm without understanding why the algorithm gives the correct answer. The OP is trying to learn; I don't understand why you're picking a fight with him.

Answer (score 1):

$t$ is considered constant because of the differential $dx$, which indicates that you must differentiate with respect to $x.$

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure if there was more to the concept than that.

Comment: For more information you may want to do some research on differentials.

Comment: I will do that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int t x \quad dx$$ is just an expression that makes us *extract* the antiderivative of the function in the integral (in your case the function is $f(x) = x$).

So why I put $f(x) = x$ and not $f(t) =t$? Because the $dx$ tells us that we're differentiating with respect to $x$ and not to $t$. Indeed the title is wrong $\ldots$ there are not 2 variables (there would be $dx dt$).

Comment: Thank you! That cleared everything up!

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about the convention. In most cases if a variable is not specifically identified as depending on another variable it is treated as a constant with respect to it. But beware, often in physics there is an underground switching from "it does not depend" to "but now it does".

In mathematics such bait and switch tactics is sometimes used in solving differential equations.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what was confusing me!